# Registering a "global listener" vs an event listener on top-level document/window

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension, event-listener, tampermonkey

This is a bit of a strange case, but please hear me out.

I'm trying to develop an extension to add keybinds for a pre-existing website. The website is designed around a lot of nested iframes that load and change in response to user feedback. I got my hotkeys working as a userscript loaded in Tampermonkey, but when I ported the exact same code to a Chrome extension, the way top-level event listeners respond to events inside iframes is completely different.

In Tampermonkey, `document.onkeydown` fires the associated callback in response to any keystroke inside any iframe, and with Chrome's developer tools I can see the event listener in the list of "Global listeners" for the whole tab.

The exact same code in an unpacked Chrome extension only registers the listener on the top-level document object, and so if the focus is inside an iframe, the callback isn't executed.

Ultimately, Tampermonkey and Chrome extensions aside, is there an explicit way to set a global listener on *all* elements, regardless of whether they're inside an iframe or not without recursively looping through them and adding the listener to each one?

I am a bit of a newcomer to Javascript and web development in general, so apologies if this is a dumb question.

(Mostly) full code here: https://pastebin.com/b6qnCMdL

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: After a bit more digging, this may have more to do with differences in how Tampermonkey matches URLs vs. how Chrome extensions match URLs.

Comment: IT is normally not allowed in the scope of origin A to listen for events in a window of origin B but extensions of course have more rights, but that could be a reason

Comment: *In Tampermonkey, document.onkeydown fires the associated callback in response to any keystroke inside any iframe* I can't reproduce. `onkeydown` when inside an iframe does not propagate up to the parent, at least not with Stack Snippets. You'll probably have to have *each iframe* add its own listener and then propagate the events upward manually.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Adding `"all_frames" = true` to the manifest.json file resulted in the same behavior I was seeing from Tampermonkey.